# VBA SQL Update Issue

Tags: sql, vba, sql-update, where-clause

Could anyone enlighten me why this SQL statement (for Access 2010) is given me errors?

```
str_SQL = "UPDATE tbl_Main " & _
          "SET [Kundennummer] = (SELECT [Kundennummer] FROM tbl_Import " & _
          "WHERE " & _
          "tbl_Main.[CML_Vertragsnummer] = tbl_Import.[CML_Vertragsnummer]);"`
```

What it should do is to update `[Kundennummer]` in `tbl_Main` from the same column in `tbl_Import` if a record is found where the values of the `[CML_Vertragsnummer]` column match.

Thanks

Comment: Only if you tell us what the error is and also indicate what kind of database - SQL Server?. And it also helps if you post the actual SQL, not just the string. I think I know the solution but I will only post it if you respond

Comment: Runtime error 3073, thats the whole sql :)
i run it with DoCmd.RunSQL (str_SQL) afterwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not joining the tables?

```
UPDATE tbl_Main 
INNER JOIN tbl_Import ON tbl_Main.CML_Vertragsnummer = tbl_Import.CML_Vertragsnummer 
SET tbl_Main.Kundennummer = tbl_Import.Kundennummer;
```

better then the sub-select and updateable :-)